# How to change shape of soft edges in MS PowerPoint?

Tags: tools, microsoft-powerpoint, pictures

In Microsoft PowerPoint (2016), you can add a soft (fading) edge to pictures via the `Picture Effects` menu. This adds a circular perimeter around rectangular/square pictures with a fading edge.

[image]

There's a set of `Soft Edge Options...` to play around with to change the size of the soft edge. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to modify the "shape" of the soft edge around such a rectangular image.

I understand that the picture effect tool is not applying a circle *per se* and is simply reacting to the edges available. However, I'm wondering if **there is some way to modify the soft edge approach so that I can acheive more of a `rounded rectangle` type of soft edge effect.**

- In other words, make the soft edges less *crcular* and instead apply a faded look to just the corners...

[image]

<sup>(Just a quick MS paint job for reference)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double-click on the picture and choose picture shape, in the middle of the picture tools tab, select Soft Edged Rectangle next to the picture styles and then use the Crop tool to crop it to your desired shape.

- Click Crop > Crop to shape
- Select one of the shapes

[image]

Comment: I *KNEW* THERE MUST BE A WAY TO DO THIS!! I just never thought to look under the crop tool! Oy! Thank you very much :).